# Flutter real device is not recognised

Tags: android, flutter, installation

I have installed flutter (Fresh installation) but not android studio. Because my laptop specifications does not meet the minimum requirements of android studio.

```
---android studio minimum requirements---
 - 64-bit Microsoft® Windows® 8/10/11.
 - x86_64 CPU architecture; 2nd generation Intel Core or newer, or AMD CPU with support for a Windows Hypervisor.
 - 8 GB RAM or more.
 - 8 GB of available disk space minimum (IDE + Android SDK + Android Emulator)
 - 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution.

---my system specifications---
 - 64-bit, x64-based processor, windows 10
 - Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7130U CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.71 GHz
 - 4 GB RAM (3.89 GB usable)
 - 1366 x 768 maximum resolution.
```

And I also don't want to install android studio.
When I run `flutter doctor` it just shows
results of flutter doctor command

[image]

Even after a real device ( USB debugging ENABLED in developer options ) is connected, the `flutter doctor` result is the same. I also tried `flutter devices` to check my real device is recognized by flutter, but it shows this.
[image: results of flutter devices command]

I just want to learn and work with flutter, but I don't want to install android studio. Is there any way it is possible?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?) for learning purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

To see how you can do this refer to this article:
https://ksrk.medium.com/install-flutter-without-android-studio-on-window-9d3781172912

Comment: Thanks man, that works really fine. Now my real device is recognized on flutter. But there is this error when i run "flutter doctor --android-licenses". It says "Android  sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this." Is it ignorable or i need to work on it too.

Comment: over came the "flutter doctor --android-licenses" ERROR by running ( sdkmanager --update ) and ( sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest" ) commands and it works fine for me. Thanks Marcelo Abu bro.